# LibGx Box2D Pixels to Meters only drawing large objects

Tags: java, oop, box2d

Im trying to learn about the Box2D physics engine.
Im using it in LibGX, and im facing a problem.
When i convert from Pixels to Meters, only large objects are drawn..
say this:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen{
static int PPM = 100;
Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;
World w = new World(new Vector2(0,-0.981f),true);
OrthographicCamera cam;

public static Body createDynamicBody(World world, int x, int y, int w, 
    int h, int density, int scale) {
    BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
    def.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    def.position.set(x/scale,y/scale);
    Body b = world.createBody(def);
    FixtureDef fdef =new FixtureDef();
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox((w/2)/scale,(h/2)/scale);
    fdef.shape = shape;
    b.createFixture(fdef);
    return b;
}

 // initialized when Screen is loaded
 @Override
public void show() {
    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    font = new BitmapFont();
    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    cam.setToOrtho(false,800,480);
    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    // this body is not drawn
    Body b = createDynamicBody(w,200,200,150,150,5, PPM);
    // this body is drawn
    Body b2 = createDynamicBody(w,200,200,200,200,5, PPM);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.2f,0.1f,0.7f,1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    debugRenderer.render(w,camera.combined.cpy().scale(PPM,PPM,0));
    w.step(1/60f,6,2);
}

}
```

Comment: please, help :/

Answer (score 0):

In your createDynamicBody you are using an int for scale. This is causing you to loose precision when you divide. Simple replace your int scale with float scale and it should work.

```
public static Body createDynamicBody(World world, int x, int y, int w, 
                                            int h, int density, float scale)
```

Comment: managed to fix it, PPM should have been float not int.. Thanks :)